# Downloading all dependencies on Windows and installing them on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management

I need to install openssh on my Ubuntu 32bit VM. However I cannot straight do `apt-get install openssh-server` as it fails in resolving many required dependencies. Thanks to my companies super creepy proxy settings. Now I have all Windows machine here and one 64 bit Ubuntu with openssh installed. So I cannot copy paste .deb from this machine to my Ubuntu VM and install as my deb packages will have different architecture (32 bit vs 64 bit).

So I went on downloading 32 bit packages from [this site](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) (Thank god, my company's IS team has not discovered this website yet!!!). However I dont know what all packages will be required by openssh as its dependencies. I checked my Ubuntu 64 bit machine. By sorting `var\cache\apt\archive` by date, I realised that on the day when I installed openssh on that machine, following packages were installed:

- openssh-sftp-server
- openssh-server
- openssh-client
- libck-connector0

So here is what I did:

- I downloaded debs of 32 bit versions of the above from [the site](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) and ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. It said it requires `ssh-import-id` package.
- I downloaded `ssh-import-id` and again run above command again. It said "`ssh-import-id` is not configured yet as it requires `python-requests`".
- I downloaded that and ran the command. It said "`python-requests` is not configured yet as it requires `python-urllib3`".
- So I downloaded `python-urllib3` and ran the command. This time it said "`libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.9-ubuntu3)` breaks `python-urllib3 (<< 1.9.1-3)` and is installed"

I guess I installed wrong versions and also at each step when the installation failed, the some of the packages were installed, some were not and those which were installed are left ill-configured. So each time I ran `sudo dpkg -i`, I should have uninstalled the packages I installed ealier.

I feel this is a lot of pain. Also it is very difficult to know and install correct versions of all dependencies. Is there any way by which I can:

1. Capture list of currently installed packages on my VM,
2. Upload it on some site,
3. Specify what I want to install next and
4. in return that website would tell me what all `.deb` packages I will need

I would have downloaded all those manually from above site and then installed them.

Is there any such way? What other options I am left with?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install gdebi.deb for your architecture.
Download openssh-server.deb. Right-click on it and choose "Install with gdebi" option. Gdebi will tell you about missing dependencies, one-by-one. Download each depending deb package and install them one-by-one using Gdebi. I know it's an excruciating pain when having many dependencies to meet, but it's the only failsafe method i know. I just hope you'll have the patience for it.

Comment: am thinking to have another VM running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS at my home. Clean its `var/cache/apt/archive`. Then install `openssh-server`. Finally copy all newly downloaded debs from `var/cache/apt/archive` of my home VM to my office VM and then install from debs. Will this work?

Comment: Why having another VM? VMs are creating virtual-hard-disks as single very large file (e.g. vm_name.vdi). VMs are installing OS in that file. A Ubuntu 32bit VM file could be as little as 10GB, i think. You can copy that file to an sd card, usb stick, etc, take it home and run it on your PC. It should work fine. I've done that, running a LinuxMint VM in VirtualBox in Ubuntu, and then running the same VM in VirtualBox in Windows.

Comment: OR You could try a portable app for Windows like this one: http://www.pendriveapps.com/mobaxterm-portable-x-server-and-ssh-client/. Many PortableApps.com software are known to run well in Ubuntu under Wine. One app for both Win and Ubuntu! Take it everywhere with you.

Comment: Office PC's USBs are blocked... So taking anything that big out of my office PC would be difficult. I was planning to move debs through mail. Debs shouldn't be that big. Anyways will my above approach work?

Comment: Possible. I didn't try it. Such server might have dozens of debs required. Or you could try to use Microsoft Azure (very hot technology) and create a Ubuntu VM in Azure, in the cloud. Set up your ssh-server in there and access it everywhere without hassle. Or copy it locally. Your choice.